# How to insert text at the beginning and ending of a specified line?

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to insert some text at the beginning and ending of a specified number line, like i have this txt file :

```
apple
banana
orange
pineapple
```

To insert at the beginning and ending for the first line i use :

```
while read -r line
do
sed "1i[text_insert]$line" > outputfile1
done < inputfile

while read -r line
do
sed "1i$line[text_insert2]" > outputfile2
done < outputfile1
```

and i obtain :

```
[text_insert]apple[text_insert2]
banana
orange
pineapple
```

And now i would like to add some text at the line number 2:

```
[text_insert]apple[text_insert2]
[text_insert3]banana[text_insert4]
orange
pineapple
```

I tried to use the same thing but that doesn't work and all the other possibilities that i found are to insert text like a new line before a specified line and not to add it in a specified line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following snippet :

```
sed '2s/.*/[text_insert] & [text_insert2]/' file.txt
```

`&` have a special meaning: it's the matching part from the left part of the *substitution* `s///`

Ex :

```
$ cat file.txt 
a
b
c

$ sed '2s/.*/[text_insert] & [text_insert2]/' file.txt 
a
[text_insert] b [text_insert2]
c
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
$ line=3
$ awk -v num=$line 'NR==num{$0="[Insert New Text] " $0 " [Insert End Text]"}1' file
apple
banana
[Insert New Text] orange [Insert End Text]
pineapple
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to accomplish what you need with the built-in NR variable. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    if (NR == 1)
        printf("[text_insert] %s [text_insert2]\n", $0)
    else if (NR == 2)
        printf("[text_insert3] %s [text_insert4]\n", $0)
    else
        print $0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `awk` is an option :

```
$ cat file.txt 
a
b
c

$ awk 'NR==2{printf "[text_insert] %s [text_insert2]\n", $0;next}1' file.txt 
a
[text_insert] b [text_insert2]
c
```

Comment: As you mention in your example, the result is "[text_insert] b [text_insert]b"; and i don't want again the line in the end. So i prefer your first answer. (but it also works :)

Comment: It was an old version, try the newest. No repetition anymore.